#  Clickable compound drawable in EditText that pops a view on click

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am using TextWatcher to validate my input and I want my red hint image to be clickable so I can give the user visual feedback as shown in the image below. What I have until now is the edit text with the red hint image appearing when I enter invalid data. I now want to know how to make this red hint clickable and make pop-up hint appear as shown.

[image: EditText hint]

This is the code I have so far,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

    EditText username,email = null;
    boolean flag=false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      

        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernametxt);
        email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtxt);

        username.addTextChangedListener(this);

        username.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // your code here...
            if(flag)
            {
                email.setText("Error. . .");
            }
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);                
            return false;
            }
        });

        Button loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Check Validations
                if(username.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    username.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.alert, 0);
                    flag=true;
                }
            }
        });

        Button clearbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clearbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                username.setText("");
                email.setText("");      
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        username.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        flag=false;
        email.setText("");
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Akki The image posted is what I would like to achieve. I now have the red image only when the user enters invalid data. I want to make the pop-up shown in the image appear when the user clicks on the red image  hint.

Comment: I'm still now quite sure I understand the problem.

Comment: I implemented a similar feature with `PopupWindow` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: @MichalK how do I make the red hint image in the editText clickable so I can then use popupwindow?

Comment: With onClickListener which can be attached to any `View`, including your `ImageView`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make a custom `EditText` to get the first feature.

[Solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext)

The popup view on clicking the drawable can be done with a `PopupWindow`

[Solved here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664386/inserting-textview-inside-edittext-in-android/10664561#10664561)

Comment: Popupwindow is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple if you use the red hint image as a compound drawable to the right of your EditText usernametxt.
Following will do the trick.

```
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernametxt);
username.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getRawX() >= username.getRight() - username.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                // your action for drawable click event

             return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you want for left drawable change the if statement to:

```
if(event.getRawX() <= username.getTotalPaddingLeft())
```

Similarly, you can do it for all compound drawables.

```
username.getTotalPaddingTop()
username.getTotalPaddingBottom()
```

This method call returns all the padding on that side including any drawables. You can use this even for TextView, Button etc.

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTotalPaddingBottom()) for reference from android developer site.