# how set margin between spannable textview?

Tags: android, textview, margins, spannable

I am trying to create spannable textview and showing it in EditText. So user can type something in EditText and if user pressed enter button of keyboard then i am converting this text in to spannable textview after this user can start typing again and press enter button of keyboard then again second spannable textview will create ans will show it in edittext but.

**Where i stuck?**

when i create two spannable textview then this two textview slightly overlapping on each other. And i want to set margin between this two textview.

I also tried to set margin between textview using [LayoutParam](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) but not success.

Here is image which showing textview overlapping on each other in EditText.

[image]

*y* of *spicy* is hidden below *tasty*

Here is my code.

```
txtDishTags.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                txtDishTags.dismissDropDown();
                  if(txtDishTags.getText().toString().trim().length()>=1){
                isEntered = true;

                String[] separated = tags.split(",");
                tags = separated[separated.length-1];
                if(tags.trim().length()>=1){
                TextView tv = createContactTextView(tags);
                BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(tv);
                bd.setBounds(-20, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                        bd.getIntrinsicHeight());
                sb.append(tags + ",");
                sb1 = new SpannableStringBuilder();
                sb1.append(tags + ",");
                sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd),
                        sb.length() - tags.length(), sb.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                sb.setSpan(clickSpan, sb.length() - tags.length(),
                        sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                txtDishTags.setText("");
                txtDishTags.setText(sb);    
                int length = sb.length();
                txtDishTags.setSelection(length, length);
                }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });  

public TextView createContactTextView(String text) {
    //llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 44);
        //llp.setMargins(5, 0, 20, 0);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setTextSize(30);     
    Typeface faceBook = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/eau_sans_book.otf");
    tv.setTypeface(faceBook);   
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundcolor));
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.textviewbubble);
    //tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
    Resources r = getResources();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            44, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    tv.setHeight(px);
    return tv;
}

public static Object convertViewToDrawable(View view) {
    int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    view.measure(spec, spec);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
            view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
    view.draw(c);
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap cacheBmp = view.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    view.destroyDrawingCache();
    return new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
}
```

I tried to set margin between textview using following code

```
 llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 44);
 llp.setMargins(5, 0, 20, 0);
 tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

I also set LeftPadding for Textview but seems first textview not getting it.Even i set height to textview but seems textview not getting layout parameter at all.  Like

```
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        44, r.getDisplayMetrics());
tv.setHeight(px);
```

Please give reference or hint.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your full activity ?

Comment: i already put all relevant code. there is nothing outside this.

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil what is tags? When is it updated?

Comment: when i click on search key of keyboard then tag will create. if i type again something and then click on again search button then second tag will create.

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil ok please follow my answer. It should resolve your problem :)

Comment: @AmulyaKhare :have you done with delete code... i am trying but not getting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few problems that I have identified. You need to make the specified changes and everything should work.

**Step 1) Update `setBounds` parameters**

In the following line, update the `setBounds` parameters from `-20` to `0` as follows:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(tv);
bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), bd.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

This is important because you are setting the wrong bounds, which causes tags to overlap.

**Step 2) Fix bug in `sb.setSpan`**

If you followed step 1, and you run the code, you will realize that when you attempt to replace text with `ImageSpan`, you are passing the wrong values (you are not taking into account the `","`(comma) character in the end). Update the following line to include `-1`:

```
sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), sb.length() - tags.length() - 1, sb.length() - 1,
           Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Now you output will appear correct and with comma in the middle.

[image]

**Step 3) Add spacing between Tags**

To answer your original question, how to add spacing, I would recommend that you modify your code to include `", "` between different spans. You can also modify it to use just `" "` space. Define a `contentBetweenTags` variable and set it to your desired value. Here is how you can do that:

```
String contentBetweenTags = ", ";
sb.append(tags + contentBetweenTags);
sb1 = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb1.append(tags + contentBetweenTags);
sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), 
           sb.length() - tags.length() - contentBetweenTags.length(), 
           sb.length() - contentBetweenTags.length(), 
           Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

**Step 4) Picking the right *"space"* character**

Just in case you are not happy with the "margin/spacing" between two tags, you could use one of the many [unicode space characters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) available. They have different widths and you could use any one of them based on your desire / liking.

Here is the final code and sample screenshot using unicode `\u2002`:

[image]

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) convertViewToDrawable(tv);
bd.setBounds(0, 0, bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), bd.getIntrinsicHeight());
String contentBetweenTags = ",\u2002";
sb.append(tags + contentBetweenTags);
sb1 = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb1.append(tags + contentBetweenTags);
sb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bd), 
           sb.length() - tags.length() - contentBetweenTags.length(), 
           sb.length() - contentBetweenTags.length(), 
           Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Can you do one more favor... I want to delete tag from spannable string builder using delete ket listener but getting some problem.... can you add delete code as well....

Comment: what i want, suppose i have two tag in edittext and some text... if i delete some text(which is not tag) and now Edittext have only tags now. if i press del then last tags background color will change and if i press again del then last tag will be delete from string builder ans vise versa...

Comment: I will have to take a look regarding this issue.. Sure no problem.